# Centering in non-merged tables?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

This is the snippet I'm working on:

```
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}[hbt!]
        \centering
        \begin{tabularx}{5.75in}%
            {@{} P{1in} P{0.4in} P{0.4in} P{0.5in} P{0.5in} P{0.4in} P{0.4in} P{0.5in} P{0.5in} @{}}
            \toprule
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{Average Accuracy}}} 
                        & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{ResNet-50}}                                    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{MobileNet-V2}} \tabularnewline
            \cmidrule(lr){2-9}
                        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Segmentation}      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Non-Segmentation}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Segmentation}      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Non-Segmentation} \tabularnewline
            \cmidrule(lr){2-9}
                        & \centering SVM    &  \centering KNN   & \centering SVM    &  \centering KNN   & \centering SVM    &  \centering KNN   & \centering SVM    & \centering SVM    &  \centering  KNN \tabularnewline
            \midrule
            Training    & 0.85      & 0.74          & 0.73          & 0.72          & 0.76      & 0.70          & 0.70          & 0.69 \tabularnewline
            Test        & 0.84      & 0.73          & 0.72          & 0.70          & 0.75      & 0.69          & 0.69          & 0.62 \tabularnewline
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
        \caption{Cassava Disease Detection System Performance Results \parencite{Sedat2021Disease}}
        \label{table:Cassava Disease Detection System Performance Results}
    \end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

However, the centering on line 3 only works for merged cells so I have to manually center the text for non-merged cells. However, I had encountered an error many are familiar with centering the last column of text. Anyone have an idea how to fix it? Your help is very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What's the column specifier `P`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have too long headers and subheaders: abbreviate them. This way, landscape mode is not needed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[hbtp!]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  l
  *{8}{S[table-format=1.2]}
  @{}
}
\toprule
\smash{\bfseries\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}Average \\ Accuracy\end{tabular}} &
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{ResNet-50}} &
\multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{\textbf{MobileNet-V2}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-5} \cmidrule(l){6-9}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{S} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{NS}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{S} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{NS} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7} \cmidrule(l){8-9}
& {SVM} & {KNN} & {SVM} & {KNN} & {SVM} & {KNN} & {SVM} & {KNN} \\
\midrule
Training  & 0.85 & 0.74 & 0.73 & 0.72 & 0.76 & 0.70 & 0.70 & 0.69 \\
Test      & 0.84 & 0.73 & 0.72 & 0.70 & 0.75 & 0.69 & 0.69 & 0.62 \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{9}{@{}l@{}}{\strut\footnotesize S: Segmented; NS: Nonsegmented}
\end{tabular}

\caption{Cassava Disease Detection System Performance Results \parencite{Sedat2021Disease}}
\label{table:Cassava Disease Detection System Performance Results}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

After seeing the output you may want to spread the table to the text width.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[hbtp!]

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}% leave TeX the spacing

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  *{8}{S[table-format=1.2]}
}
\toprule
\smash{\bfseries\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}Average \\ Accuracy\end{tabular}} &
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{ResNet-50}} &
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{MobileNet-V2}} \\
\cmidrule{2-5} \cmidrule{6-9}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{S} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{NS}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{S} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{NS} \\
\cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-5} \cmidrule{6-7} \cmidrule{8-9}
& {SVM} & {KNN} & {SVM} & {KNN} & {SVM} & {KNN} & {SVM} & {KNN} \\
\midrule
Training  & 0.85 & 0.74 & 0.73 & 0.72 & 0.76 & 0.70 & 0.70 & 0.69 \\
Test      & 0.84 & 0.73 & 0.72 & 0.70 & 0.75 & 0.69 & 0.69 & 0.62 \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{9}{l}{\strut\footnotesize S: Segmented; NS: Nonsegmented}
\end{tabular*}

\caption{Cassava Disease Detection System Performance Results \parencite{Sedat2021Disease}}
\label{table:Cassava Disease Detection System Performance Results}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice one, though how would I center average accuracy?

Comment: @KennethLigutom Use `\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}Average \\ Accuracy\end{tabular}}`

Comment: Gotcha, thank you @egreg!

Comment: I tried your fix but it didn't work. The output looked the exact same @egreg as your answer. Maybe due to other packages I added?

Comment: Also I meant vertical centering @egreg

Comment: @KennethLigutom No, you don't want that… Trust me.

Comment: Why though? Office Word has that option @egreg

Comment: @KennethLigutom That doesn't make it typographically sound. Quite likely it should be a further header above columns 2 to 9, but in my opinion it should simply be specified in the caption.