# Converting a tabular table to a tabularray table

Tags: tables, tabularray

Right now, I'm converting my tabular table to a tabularray one after I asked [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/714379/centering-in-non-merged-tables) where this is my desired output but the first column is centered vertically: [image]

Right now I have problems with converting to a tabularray code:

```
\begin{table}[hbtp!]
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt} % leave TeX the spacing
    \begin{tblr}{ccccccccc}
        \toprule
        \SetCell[r=3,c=1]{c} Average Accuracy & \SetCell[c=4]{c}ResNet-50 & \SetCell[c=4]{c}MobileNet-V2 \\
        \cmidrule{2-5} \cmidrule{6-9}
        & \SetCell[c=2]{c} S    & \SetCell[c=2]{c} NS   & \SetCell[c=2]{c} S    & \SetCell[c=2]{c} NS \\
        \cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-5} \cmidrule{6-7} \cmidrule{8-9}
        & {SVM} & {KNN} & {SVM} & {KNN} & {SVM} & {KNN} & {SVM} & {KNN} \\
        \midrule
        Training  & 0.85 & 0.74 & 0.73 & 0.72 & 0.76 & 0.70 & 0.70 & 0.69 \\
        Test      & 0.84 & 0.73 & 0.72 & 0.70 & 0.75 & 0.69 & 0.69 & 0.62 \\
        \bottomrule
        \SetCell{c=9} \footnotesize S: Segmented; NS: Nonsegmented \\
    \end{tblr}
    \caption{Cassava Disease Detection System Performance Results \parencite{Sedat2021Disease}}
    \label{table:Cassava Disease Detection System Performance Results}
\end{table}
```

LaTeX threw these errors, but I think they are all due to how I code the table. I dunno where did I go wrong though since the columns and rows match.

[image]

Your help is very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Yes @Mico. The screenshot shows the error, the code is just a MWE.

Comment: I meant the design of the output, not necessarily the content.

Comment: Gotcha. I just used it as a reference @Mico

Comment: No. The design choice was never an error @Mico. I only pointed out the error log I sent to accompany the code that I meant to add. I'm sorry that I confused you with what I wrote in the comment earlier in this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three changes to replicate the screenshot:

- For the first column I would suggest `X[halign=l]` instead of `c`. This allows line breaks within the cells and also allows the table to adjust its width to span the whole text width
- Use `\cmidrule[lr]{4-5}` to shorten the rules one the left and/or right side to get some space between them
- If you merge cells over multiple columns in tabularray, you nevertheless have to list all the `&` of the skipped cells. If you don't do this, cells will be missing.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={@{}X[halign=l,1.2]XXXXXXXX@{}},
  column{2-Z}={halign=c},
  hspan=even
}
    \toprule
    \SetCell[r=3]{} Average Accuracy & \SetCell[c=4]{}ResNet-50 &&&& \SetCell[c=4]{}MobileNet-V2 &&& \\
    \cmidrule{2-5} \cmidrule{6-9}
    & \SetCell[c=2]{} Segmentation    && \SetCell[c=2]{} Non-Segmentation   && \SetCell[c=2]{} Segmentation    && \SetCell[c=2]{} Non-Segmentation &\\
    \cmidrule[r]{2-3} \cmidrule[lr]{4-5} \cmidrule[lr]{6-7} \cmidrule[l]{8-9}
    & {SVM} & {KNN} & {SVM} & {KNN} & {SVM} & {KNN} & {SVM} & {KNN} \\
    \midrule
    Training  & 0.85 & 0.74 & 0.73 & 0.72 & 0.76 & 0.70 & 0.70 & 0.69 \\
    Test      & 0.84 & 0.73 & 0.72 & 0.70 & 0.75 & 0.69 & 0.69 & 0.62 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Though how about if I add legends @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz to fit with my A4-sized bond paper?

Comment: @KennethLigutom The paper size does not matter, what matters is the size of your text block. As long as it is wide enough to fit your table, tabularry will automatically adapt the width to fit the size of your text block.

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you!

Comment: One last thing, what does `column{2-Z}={halign=c}` do @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz?

Comment: @KennethLigutom This centres the text horizontally in all but the first column.